# Como alterar o comprimento de um input em asp.net MVC

Tags: html5, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-3

Olá, estou tendo muita dificuldade em alterar a largura(comprimento) de um input em `asp.net MVC`, segui as orientações dos cursos e não deu certo.

segue o código da minha `view`, se alguém puder ajudar....

Não posso atualizar o `bootstrap` 3.7 para a versão 4, tive incompatibilidade com os plugins em `javascript`.

```css
<style>
    body {
        background-color: beige;
        overflow-y: visible;
        overflow-x: visible
    }
</style>
```

```html
@model SIIv3.Models.CAD_CIDADE

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Novo Cadastro";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Inserir um novo registro</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @*<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CODCIDADE, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CODCIDADE, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CODCIDADE, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>*@

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CIDADE, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CIDADE, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CIDADE, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UF, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UF, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UF, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Inserir" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Voltar para listagem geal", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

segue um a página gerada após o processamento.

```
insira o código aqui

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Create - Sistema de Informação Integrado</title>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data- 
toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">SII</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data- 
 toggle="dropdown">Injetora<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="font-size: 1em">
 href="/RastreamentoLotesInjetora">Rastreamento de Lotes</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data- 
 toggle="dropdown">Silos Externos<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="font-size: 1em">
                        <li><a href="/SiloExterno">Monitoramento</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data- 
toggle="dropdown">Lista de Presença<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="font-size: 1em">
                        <li><a 
href="/ListaPresenca/ConsultaEscalaFolga">Escala Folgas</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>



<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

    <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Account/Register" 
id="registerLink">Registre-se</a></li>

    <li class="nav-item ml-2"><a href="/Account/Login" 
id="loginLink">Entrar</a></li>
</ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="containerbody">
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: black;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }
    </style>
 <h2>Create</h2>
<link href="/Content/EstiloPersonalizado.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form action="/cad_statusevento/Create" method="post"><input 
name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" 
value="v5dSscXvRgLd98jnLHTonXiWPOhms201e4suasgaflOJALyMjzL7E9gxn3J4- 
QSbLub8ntkkX5L_FRMfMX4kYgExKw7bxIVf55bD9oKoKq01" />    <div class="form- 
horizontal col-md-12">
    <h4>CAD_STATUSEVENTO</h4>
    <hr />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" 
for="DESCRICAOSTATUSEVENTO">Evento</label>
        <div class="" style="width: 2000px">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" 
data-val-length="Insira uma descrição de 1 a 30 caracteres" data-val-length- 
max="30" data-val-required="Entre com a descrição da Evento" 
id="DESCRICAOSTATUSEVENTO" name="DESCRICAOSTATUSEVENTO" style="width: 500px" 
type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg- 
for="DESCRICAOSTATUSEVENTO" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<div>
   <a href="/cad_statusevento">Back to List</a>
</div>
</div>
   <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Roberto porque vc já não coloca col-md-12 e não 10? Tem como vc postar o código que é renderizado no browser ou um print da tela explicando melhor?

Comment: segue a página e tirei um printscreen, gostaria que inputbox ficasse maior, já tinha mudado para col-md-12, mas não adiantou. é como se o comprimento da tela estive limitado a metade da tela.

Comment: Roberto eu pequei o código que vc postou na edição e ajustei o que precisava. Acho que ficou como vc queria, mas se tiver alguma dúvida é só comentar lá na resposta que te ajudo.

Comment: olá, consegui descobrir o problema. O arquivo Site.CSS estava mantendo todos os inputs com o tamanho fixo. remove a linha e deu certo. Obrigado pela atenção.